# SQL Query for the player and vsplayer

Tags: sql, sql-server

Team Table

```
Player (column)
A
B
C
```

Expected Output: with Two columns

```
Player   vsPlayer
A           B
B           C
C           A
```

How to write a sql query to get the exact output as Expected output mentioned above.
Thanks in advance

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. Please teak a minute to get the [tour], and read [ask]. Also, specifically to SQL Server questions, you should read the guidelines in the [sql server tag info](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/sql-server/info). Once you've done that, please [edit] your question according to these guidelines.

Comment: What is this supposed to be? It's the same as "I have soil and I have rain - expected result is vegetable"... WHat have you tried so far?

Comment: *"Help Required"* With what?

Comment: @Larnu Obviously they need another player to fill the team

Comment: Not really; might be on how to ask a question, @GeorgeMenoutis , as they haven't asked one here, yet they have posted a question. They haven't explained what the problem *they* are having is, so we don't know what help they need. Hand holding isn't help, in my opinion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal way to get combination (pairs) is to take all permutations, but where column 1 is less than column 2.

```
SELECT
  l.player,
  r.player
FROM
  player   l
INNER JOIN
  player   r
    ON l.player < r.player
```

Demo : https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=9ce7af3d0afe89c6434cc2800dfbd2ef